# Получить значение select Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

подскажите есть селект , в `dataObject.call_status` приходит значение `null`, 1 или 0

Как сделать чтоб если `dataObject.call_status == 1` или 0 , тогда выбрать option с соответствующим значением ? но так же иметь возможность выбирать из списка

К примеру если `dataObject.call_status == 1` тогда Дозвон, но я хочу поменть на Не дозвон то value должно быть 0

```
<select class="form-control mb-3" @change="changeCallStatus($event)">
       <option v-if="dataObject.call_status == null" value=""></option>
       <option value="0">Не дозвон</option>
       <option value="1">Дозвон</option>
    </select>

changeCallStatus(event){
                console.log(event.target.value)
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select class="form-control mb-3" @change="changeCallStatus($event)">
  <option :selected="dataObject.call_status === 0"" value="0">Не дозвон</option>
  <option :selected="dataObject.call_status === 1"" value="1">Дозвон</option>
</select>

changeCallStatus(event){
  console.log(event.target.value)
}
```